# Remove a object from List

Tags: java, list

which one you perfer to remove if i need to remove a object from List , suppose String "abc"
linkedList or ArrayList ? ( I think, both are same)
and what is the time and space complexity if i go with Linkedlist and arraylist
(I believe that both will have same time complexity of O(n)

Comment: both are not same...check here...http://stackoverflow.com/q/322715/2764279

Comment: Minimal research is required before asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both will have the same time complexity - O(n), but IMHO, the `LinkedList` version will be faster especially in large lists, because when you remove an element from array (`ArrayList`), all elements on the right will have to shift left - in order to fill in the emptied array element, while the `LinkedList` will only have to rewire 4 references

Here are the time complexities of the other list methods:

```
For LinkedList<E>

    get(int index) - O(n)
    add(E element) - O(1)
    add(int index, E element) - O(n)
    remove(int index) - O(n)
    Iterator.remove() is O(1) 
    ListIterator.add(E element) - O(1) 

For ArrayList<E>

    get(int index) is O(1) 
    add(E element) is O(1) amortized, but O(n) worst-case since the array must be resized and copied
    add(int index, E element) is O(n - index) amortized,  O(n) worst-case 
    remove(int index) - O(n - index) (removing last is O(1))
    Iterator.remove() - O(n - index)
    ListIterator.add(E element) - O(n - index)
```